# How to collapse 2D scatter plot into a dot plot?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, scatter-plot, scatter

I have a very large 2d array of shape *(186295, 2)* with the first element of every 2-element sub-array being x and the second element being y. Here is how I produce the scatter plot by separating x and y components in `matplotlib`:

```
ax.scatter(A[:, 0]+np.random.uniform(-.02, .02, A.shape[0]), A[:, 1], s=2, color='b', alpha=0.5, zorder=3)
```

[image: scatter plot]

However, I would like

all points with x-value in the range [8,9.2] be shown as a dot plot at the mid point *x=8.6*,

all points with x-value in the range [9.2,10.4] be shown as a dot plot at the mid point *x=9.8*,

all points with x-value in the range [10.4,12.2] be shown as a dot plot at the mid point *x=11.3*.

Your help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n=100
x = np.random.uniform(8, 12, n)
y = np.random.uniform(.01, 1, n)
a = np.array(list(zip(x,y)))


fig,ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
ax[0].scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1])
ax[0].title.set_text('Scatter Plot')

conditions = [a[:,0]<=8, a[:,0]<=9.2, a[:,0]<=10.4, a[:,0]<=12.2, a[:,0]>12.2]
choices = [a[:,0], 8.6, 9.8, 11.3, a[:,0]]
a[:,0] = np.select(conditions, choices)

ax[1].scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1])
ax[1].title.set_text('Dot Plot')
```

Result:

[image: tit]

Another possibility is using [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) which saves some typing as it uses a list of bins (upper bounds) instead of a list of conditions.

Comment: Thank You, I could have never thought of this,

Comment: Since we know that everything has x value between [8,12.2], why we are not defining out conditions as 8<= <9.2, 9.2<= <10.4, 10.4<= 12.2 as three conditions instead?

Comment: in this special case you could do it, but in the general case if you have values outside the defined intervals then they will be set to zero (unless you pass a default value as third argument to np.select)